# TIE Fighter instructions

Tags: instructions, star-wars

Need to know what instructions go with this set. Bought them this year from LEGO store.  My kids lost the instructions. Comes with three separate bags in the set. Please help I'm trying to give it to my neighbor kid. My boys are still way too young for this set.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.StackExchange! Do you know the set number of this TIE Fighter? Is it the First Order Tie Fighter (set number 75101)? http://brickset.com/sets/75101-1/First-Order-Special-Forces-TIE-Fighter ... Instructions for this set are found [here](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6136399.pdf)....

Answer (score 3):

LEGO have instructions for all their recent sets, and many older ones available directly from their website:

https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions

There you can search for a specific set number, or search by theme ("Star Wars TM") and year of release - for example [75101 can be found here](https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&text=75101).